# Counting as January date even if cell is empty

Tags: excel

I have a table that counts which Member of staff placed a person into employment

```
*****************************************
* Advisor       * Jan * Feb * Mar * Apr *
*****************************************
*    John       *  2  *  0  *  2  *  1  *
*    Joe        *  1  *  2  *  4  *  0  *
*    Suzy       *  5  *  5  *  0  *  0  *
*****************************************
```

Using my formula below it does correctly tell me the information, but if the `Outcome Startdate` field on the `Database` form is blank then it counts it in the Jan stat. What am I doing wrong?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Database[Advisor]=B12)*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2)*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2))))
```

Comment: try this: `=SUMPRODUCT((Database[Advisor]=B12)*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2))*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2)))` I think you had a `)` out of place.

Comment: Hi, sadly it still shows the same result

Comment: Try this then: `=SUMPRODUCT((Database[Advisor]=B12)*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2))*(LEN(Database[Outcome Startdate]>0)))`

Comment: Nope sadly that didn't work :-/

Comment: In those "blank" cells, are the truly blank or do the have spaces in them?

Comment: I am going to assume that there are spaces in the "blank" cells so try this:  `=SUMPRODUCT((Database[Advisor]=B12)*(MONTH(Database[Outcome Startdate])=MONTH(C2))*(LEN(TRIM(Database[Outcome Startdate]))>0))`